# Help With Euclid's Proof that there are Infinite Primes

Tags: prime-numbers

I need some help understanding a given proof so that I can in turn prove something.
In a question I am given that:

> In order to prove that there is no "largest" prime number, for any prime $p$ just show there is a new prime $q$ such that $q>p$. Write $$N=(2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot...\cdot p)+1,$$ and if $N$ is prime we are done, otherwise $N$ is divisible by some prime $q$.

I am told to prove $q>p$. I think I can figure out how to do this, but there is one thing I don't understand in the above box. I understand how the proof is done when $N$ is prime, but I don't understand why "$N$ is divisible by some prime $q$" otherwise.

May somebody please help me understand why this is true. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I mentioned it below, but in order to hit all the natural numbers, we need our arbitrary $N$ representation to include powers of primes as well too, so $N=(2^{k_1}\cdot{3}^{k_2}\cdot...\cdot{p}^{k_n})+1$ and $\{2,3,5,...,p\}$ is our set of finite primes.

Comment: @ChristopherErnst yes I saw you mention that below and I understand why we need $N$ to be written that way. Thanks.

Comment: does my example help to clarify your understanding?

Comment: @ChristopherErnst yes it certainly does help me understand why $N$ must be divisible by some other prime $q$. Now I can also see why $q>p$.

Comment: It is not relevant whether $N$ is prime or not. Every number $n\gt 1$ is divisible by some prime. If the number is a prime, like $n=17$, then $n$ is divisible by $17$, for $17=17\cdot 1$. So there **always** exists a prime $q$ such that $q$ divides $N$. We can now argue that $q$ cannot be any of $2,3,5,\dots,p$, since when we divide $N$ by any of these, we get a remainder of $1$. So any prime divisor $q$ of $N$ must be greater than $p$. This is because in forming $N$ we have used **all** the primes $\le p$.

Answer (score 3):

Assume the primes are finite. So $N=(2^{k_1}⋅3^{k_2}⋅...⋅p^{k_n})+1$. But since there are finitely many, $N$ should also be written as a product of our finite number of primes (since it is NOT in its present form). Now, what happens then you try to do this? I.E., can you divide N by 2? how about 3? How about $p$?....

Hint:
$$N=2(2^{k_1-1}3^{k_2}5^{k_3}...p^{k_n})+1 \text{ so } 2\text{ does not divide }N$$
$$N=3(2^{k_1}3^{k_2-1}5^{k_3}...p^{k_n})+1 \text{ so } 3\text{ does not divide }N$$
$$...$$
$$N=p(2^{k_1}3^{k_2}5^{k_3}...p^{k_n-1})+1 \text{ so } p\text{ does not divide }N$$
Turns out you can not divide $N$ by any of our primes given, but $N$ $must$ be written as a product of primes, then there must exist a prime $q$ that divides $N$, and I think it's easy to see that this prime is greater than $p$

Comment: This really doesn't make sense. "So $N=\dots$"? And to arrive at the contradiction to having a complete list, there's no need to produce any more than *one* additional prime not on our list. So there's no need to confuse matters with all those exponents.

Comment: I see what your saying.  It's not about the totality of the natural numbers but about the contradition to the idea the primes are finite.  Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

$\textit{Every}$ integer is divisible by some prime, so if $N$ is not itself prime, then $N$ is divisible by some prime $q<N$.

You know that $q$ is greater than $p$ because $N$ is one more than a multiple of any prime less than or equal to $p$ (you can probably make this a little more formal, but that's the basic idea).

Comment: I understand what you are saying until you say "than a multiple of any prime less that $p$" because isn't $N$ one more than a multiple of any prime less than and including $p$? The concept you are conveying is clear, I just want a little clarification on that bit you said.

Comment: in your problem you have $N$ as $N=(2\cdot{3}\cdot{5}\cdot...\cdot{p})+1$, but in reality each prime has a power associated with it so to be completely rigorous, $N=(2^{k_1}3^{k_2}5^{k_3}...p^{k_n})+1$.